# Dificuldade no acesso de elementos em um vetor C

Tags: c

No codigo a seguir eu tento obter o maior elemento de um vetor. Entretanto ao tentar fazer acesso dos elementos do vetor eu consigo acessar somente o **índice 0** e consequentemente não consigo acessar o outros elementos do vetor.

Abaixo esta o código fonte (**main.c**):

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int *maior;
int *comparador;
int i = 0;
int quant;
int count = 0;

int CriarVetor(int tamVetor){

    int a = 1;

    int *vetorElementos = malloc(sizeof(int *) * a);

    srand(time(NULL));

    vetorElementos = realloc(vetorElementos, sizeof(int *) * tamVetor);

    for (int i = 0; i < tamVetor; i++)
    {
        vetorElementos[i] = rand() % 100;
    }


        return *vetorElementos;

}



int AcharElemento(int *vetorElementos){

    maior = vetorElementos[0];
    printf("recebi o vetor, seu primeiro elemento e %d\n", maior);
    comparador = vetorElementos[i];
    printf("vetorElementos[i] e %d\n", comparador);

    /* 

       if (i == quant) { return maior; } else {

       if (comparador > maior) { printf("entrou no if de comparacao e
       %d\n",comparador);

       maior = comparador;


       } i++; AcharElemento(&vetorElementos);

       }

     */

   return maior;
}



int main(){

    printf("Entre a quantidade de Elementos desejada\n");
    scanf("%d", &quant);

    int *elementos = CriarVetor(quant);


    printf("Os elementos do vetor sao:{");
    for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        printf("%d,", &elementos[i]);

    }
    printf("}\n");

    /* Encontrar o maior numero dentro do vetor */
    int result = AcharElemento(&elementos);
    printf("Maior Elemento e: %d\n", result);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente retirar o ponteiro do **maior** e **comparador**:

```
int maior;
int comparador;
```

Depois você deve corrigir o parametro de retorno da função `CriarVetor` de modo que retorne **int *** ao invés de **int** e a variável de retorno deve ser **vetorElementos** e não ***vetorElementos**

```
int* CriarVetor(int tamVetor){

    int a = 1;

    int *vetorElementos = malloc(sizeof(int *) * a);

    srand(time(NULL));

    vetorElementos = realloc(vetorElementos, sizeof(int *) * tamVetor);

    for (int i = 0; i < tamVetor; i++)
    {
        vetorElementos[i] = rand() % 100;
    }


        return vetorElementos;

}
```

E finalmente no **main** você deve:

1. retirar o simbolo **&** de elementos;
2. Desalocar **elementos** (não é um erro, mas uma boa prática de programação)

A função deve ficar igual abaixo:

```
int main(){    
    printf("Entre a quantidade de Elementos desejada\n");
    scanf("%d", &quant);

    int *elementos = CriarVetor(quant);

    printf("Os elementos do vetor sao:{");
    for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        printf("%d,", elementos[i]);

    }
    printf("}\n");

    /* Encontrar o maior numero dentro do vetor */
    int result = AcharElemento(elementos);
    printf("Maior Elemento e: %d\n", result);

    free(elementos);
}
```

Eu utilizei dois compiladores onlines

- [Online C Compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/BymSGujgQ)
- [Online C Compiler - ATUALIZADO](https://onlinegdb.com/SynH652lm)
- [TutorialPointer Compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php), creio que nesse site o código não fica salvo, mas usei o mesmo código.

Comment: Oi Victor,  obrigado pelo contato! Sim deu certo aqui, e consegui a funcao recursiva tambem. Porem nessa parte do codigo:     int* result = AcharElemento(elementos);
    printf("Maior Elemento e: %d\n", *result); tava dando erro de Seguimentacao, entao retirei o asterisco e funcionou, saberia me dizer o porque?

Comment: O erro ocorre porque sua função AcharElemento estav voltando um PONTEIRO e sua variável é do tipo INT.

Eu irei editar a resposta, acabei encontrando erros. assim feito e peço que avalie e se for caso, marca como solução. Essa é uma boa prática no site